# how to use ajax with graphql using get method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, graphql

I am trying to follow this documentation about `django and graphql`

https://www.techiediaries.com/django-graphql-tutorial/graphene/

I am only half way to where we can do testing with the `graphql` view and make our queries.

Then I stopped and trying to do some front end work to make query with ajax

been reading

https://blog.graph.cool/how-to-use-graphql-with-jquery-51786f0a59cb

Even though in that blog, it's using `post`.  I believe using `get` shouldn't be too much different.

So I tried making `query` into a string then `JSON.stringify` them to pass it over to the backend `django` but I keep on getting error

this is the error I have

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8000/graphql/?{"query":"query { allProducts {id sku title description } }"}. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

this is the html + jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="graphql-test">CLICK</button>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.graphql-test').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();


                var query = "query { allProducts {id sku title description } }";

                $.ajax({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: 'localhost:8000/graphql/',
                    data: JSON.stringify({"query": query}),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }

                })
            })
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: did my answer below solve it for you?

Comment: @MikeGorski no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to change your ajax call to include the full URL.

Change

```
url: 'localhost:8000/graphql/'
```

To

```
url: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/'
```

Comment: got me going though :D another stupid mistake I had that's why it's not working